# Blind SQL injection in sort direction

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

I have an SQL injection in a query where I control the sort direction parameter i.e: `SELECT * from x where y=y ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME [SORT_DIRECTION]`

When I control the `SORT_DIRECTION`, which is normally `ASC` or `DESC`,  how do I turn this into a blind SQL injection?

Comment: how about `UNION SELECT * FROM z WHERE ...`? does it have to be blind? if you can't see the output there's no point letting you control the sort order

Comment: I don't think union is going to work, the ORDER BY clause would have to go at the end of the statement. The ORDER BY clause can nonetheless be exploited, see for example: https://notsosecure.com/injection-in-order-by-clause/

Answer (score 1):

Found a partial solution:

```
,if(1=(select 1 regexp if(1=1,1,0x00)),1,1) = TRUE
,if(1=(select 1 regexp if(1=2,1,0x00)),1,1) = FALSE [error]
```

Works with `version()` but not with subqueries using `SELECT`.